# check if the url matches a specific structure

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to check if the Request.RawURL string matches a certain structure.

The structure to check would be:

```
/health/<integer>/<string>
```

e.g.

```
/health/301/personal-trainers-at-work
```

If the raw url matches this structure I want the expression to evaluate to true.

Comment: That the last value is a string or that the last value is not an int? "123" is a string for example (that can be converted to an int)

Comment: @msmucker0527 nothing, because I have no idea where to start :) @ Magnus: correct, the last value is a string, which may also contain numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this regex `/health/\d+/[\w-]+`

```
/health/ const srting    
\d+      1 or more integers    
/        const srting    
[\w-]+   1 or more alphanumeric characters _ or -
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I test this regex in VB.NET in code-behind?